# Replicating Git directory structure into local using IBM UCD

Tags: urbancode

This question relates to the usage of a continuous deployment tool of IBM which is Urban Code Deploy. We are using UCD for deploying components from our Git repository to a target machine. One of the components in the Git repo has specific folder structure, such as

```
Unix/Files/Temp/sample.ksh
```

When  I run the Download Artifact plugin of UCD, it fails to create the Gt directory structure in the target machine and place the file if the directory structure does not exist.

I want to replicate the exact same directory structure as there in the source versioning system in the target machine using Urban Code Deploy,and if directory structure is not found, UCD should create it.

How should I achieve it?  Please help.

Thanks.
Kumarjit

Comment: Does that tool have a cli, and if so: what are the exact steps to reproduce? But, for sure: 1. Use a public repo so that we have a chance at reproducing the problem. 2. Make sure you’re checking out the correct branch. Perhaps your files are in another branch?

Comment: Perhaps I am not able to convey my problem.  The directory structure Unix/Files/Temp/ does not exist in the target machine, and I want UCD to create it if the directory structure is not found and then place the sample.ksh in it, and not give "Path missing" error.

Comment: UCD should create that structure by default. But when you deploy artifacts, you need to cofngiure proper clone origin, branch, and perhaps sub-folders.

Comment: To help us replicate you must make it possible to do same thing as you’re doing. So create a new UCD deployment and deploy from any public github repository, and see if you get the same problem with the paths not being created. We can’t deploy from your private repository, so we cannot reproduce your problem that way. There may be problems with things specific to your source repository, so we must first make sure that it works for some public repository, say `https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown.git`. There are multiple folders in the master branch: try deploying that.

Comment: Thanks Kuba Ober,  the folder structures are automatically getting created by UCD. However, I am not able to get the Atrifacts downloaded from the codestation properly. How do I download the components from TestDir folder in the codestation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered by Kuba Ober

> UCD should create that structure by default. But when you deploy artifacts, you need to cofngiure proper clone origin, branch, and perhaps sub-folders.
>
> To help us replicate you must make it possible to do same thing as you’re doing. So create a new UCD deployment and deploy from any public github repository, and see if you get the same problem with the paths not being created. We can’t deploy from your private repository, so we cannot reproduce your problem that way. There may be problems with things specific to your source repository, so we must first make sure that it works for some public repository, say `https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown.git`. There are multiple folders in the master branch: try deploying that.